# How to stop Infinite scroll with recyclerview and database cursor adaptor being jumpy when loading new data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

So our android app uses recyclerview with a cursor adaptor and then we are using https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews for endless scrolling with a loader reset event (that will on the next create loader increase the limit for the amount of data we load) that will then update the view.

But the issue is, every time this happens, the recyclerview is at the bottom. So to solve that we are recording the last visible item with findFirstVisibleItemPosition and then using scrollToPosition when the view is ready.

But we have found that if the user scrolls past that point, they will get this jump / jitter as the load finishes because it loads them to that exact item when in fact they are sometimes partly thru it. We try to use scrollTo with exact X and Y (that we record beforehand) but that is not working with recyclerviews as I guess they won't know the exact dimensions of the items.

I know that we can for example only trigger this at the end of the scroll (IE have the buffer size to be 0 or 1) so we know we are at the exact end of the list and can then begin there, but we would like this to be as smooth as possible.

If there is any suggestion I would love to know.

Comment: where is your `Cursor` data coming from? is it a local sqlite database?

Comment: yeah, a local sqlite database that we read from only x number at a time, then load x+y if the user reached the top

Comment: you dont need that "endless" stuff, just use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: is that adapter mainly used so the old cursor is not closed so we use a MergeCursor with it?

Comment: you can use it with any class implementing `android.database.Cursor` interface

Comment: but if you are working with sqlite db you should just use `SQLiteCursor`, and not `MergeCursor`